# video encryption using aes

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

This code works for smaller files even mp3 and around 50mb video files but it gives me error saying out of memory when it try to encrypt larger video files(>1gb) in c# win application

AES algorithm:

```
public byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
    {
        byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                AES.KeySize = 256;
                AES.BlockSize = 128;

                var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return encryptedBytes;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How much memory do you have? Note that this code has at least two copies of the data. If you want to encrypt/decrypt large files, then you cannot produce `byte[]`, but you need to stream the data through.

Comment: how can i do that,a example would be great,,thanks

Comment: Copy a file using streams, then connect the crypto stream to the file output stream. Now get coding, lazy bones!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that you are running this as x86 and fulling the RAM available for the process. Do this to change the architecture to x64 so your only limit is the amount of RAM in your system:

1. Click on Build
2. Select "Configuration Manager"
3. Under Platform, click on New
4. Select x64 as new platform
5. Leave the default "copy settings from" (Any CPU)
6. Click ok
7. Choose x64 for every project in your solution

If the problem still happens, then you will have to split the file into smaller arrays and work with them separately.

Code example, to demonstrate how you could split the file. WARNING: This is an example, and it's not completely optimized:

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(@"D:\SomeMovie.avi");
int bytesToRead = 128 * 1024 * 1024; // 128MB 

byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead]; // create the array that will be used encrypted
long fileOffset = 0;
int read = 0;
bool allRead = false;

while (!allRead)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(info.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        fs.Seek(fileOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin); // continue reading from where we were...
        read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead); // read the next chunk
    }

    if (read == 0)
        allRead = true;
    else
        fileOffset += read;

    // encrypt the stuff, do what you need...
}
```

Comment: excatly my thought because i cant guarantee that all my target systems would be x64 so how should i split them into (large file  ->  split into     chunks->encrypt the chunks->write the encrypted chunk ->get whole encrypted file) any code regarding this would be helpful

Comment: You're encrypting a byte array, create an array with say 20% of the file, encrypt it, write it, discard it, continue to do the same with 80% remaining. I'll add a code example