# AES encryption on file over 1GB

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am making a app that will encrypt 5 video files. The problem is that it only encrypts 4 out of 5 files(the ones <1gb).
On the 5th file, which is over 1GB, the System.OutOfMemoryException is thrown.
(i know i asked it previously ,but i made some changes as suggested but it still wont work, i dont mean to spam)
Here's my code:

```
//Encrypts single file
public void EncryptFile(string file, string password)
{
    byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
    // Hash the password with SHA256
    passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

    byte[] salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(file + ".enc", FileMode.Create);

    //Set Rijndael symmetric encryption algorithm
    RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
    AES.KeySize = AES.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize;
    AES.BlockSize = AES.LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize;
    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    //"What it does is repeatedly hash the user password along with the salt." High iteration counts.
   var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 1000);
   AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
   AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
   AES.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;

   //write salt to the beginning of the output file, so in this case can be random every time
   fsCrypt.Write(salt, 0, salt.Length);

   CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
   FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);

   //create a buffer (1mb) so only this amount will allocate in the memory and not the whole file
   byte[] buffer = new byte[5048576];
   int read;

   try
   {
       while ((read = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
       {
           Application.DoEvents();
           cs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
       }

       fsIn.Close();
       fsIn.Dispose();
    }
    catch (System.OutOfMemoryException ex)
    {
        cs.Flush();
        cs.Dispose();
    }
    finally
    {
        cs.Close();
        fsCrypt.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate, asked yesterday and answered by me. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975143/video-encryption-using-aes/33977712#33977712

Comment: yup i know that but it's still not working so i thought of reposting the questions with some updates i made.
p.s i dont mean to spam

Comment: What exactly does not work? What updates did you make?

Comment: well, if you see the code i posted yesterday is working using "memorystream" and "byte", here (after googling and suggestions) i used "filestream" and tried to divide it into chunks using "buffer" but it still gives me errors. i can't seem to figure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the entire file at the start of the method:

```
byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
```

This is causing the OutOfMemoryException. Here's **an idea** of how you'd do this:

```
static void EncryptFile(string file, string password)
{
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
    byte[] salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

    RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
    AES.KeySize = AES.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize;
    AES.BlockSize = AES.LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize;
    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    //"What it does is repeatedly hash the user password along with the salt." High iteration counts.
    using (var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 1000)) // automatically dispose key
    {
        AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
        AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
        AES.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
    }
    using (FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(file + ".enc", FileMode.Create)) // automatically dispose fsCrypt
    {
        //write salt to the beginning of the output file, so in this case can be random every time
        fsCrypt.Write(salt, 0, salt.Length);
    }

    int bytesToRead = 128 * 1024 * 1024; // 128MB 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead]; // create the array that will be used encrypted
    long fileOffset = 0;
    int read = 0;
    bool allRead = false;

    while (!allRead)
    {
       using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
       {
           fs.Seek(fileOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin); // continue reading from where we were...
           read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead); // read the next chunk
       }

       if (read == 0)
           allRead = true;
       else
           fileOffset += read;

       using (FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(file + ".enc", FileMode.Open)) // automatically dispose fsCrypt
       {
           using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
           {
               fsCrypt.Seek(fileOffset, SeekOrigin.End);
               cs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: so please can you edit my (updated) code to use your method..please..thanks

Comment: after implementing your code it gives error saying "stream does not support seeking" any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @panman it seems that CryptoStream doesn't support seeking... Change this: cs.Seek(fileOffset, SeekOrigin.End); for this fsCrypt.Seek(fileOffset, SeekOrigin.End);

Comment: will try and update the result ..btw thanks for staying with me till here...really appreciated

Comment: ok tested it now the size of encrypted file is around 3~ times larger than original file (1gb original file is 6gb in size after encryption ,700 mb file is 3 gb)..is it due to encryption??

Comment: ok so is there anything i can do to keep the size close to original size

Comment: @panman not using AES, you might can using 3DES, but that's far less secure. You might want to take a look at some compression library.

Comment: ok, sir/mam thank you so much for your help...really appreciated..learned something new today because of you ,,thanks so much

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Encryption won't bloat the size of the file by **3 times**...  The largest difference in filesize that is feasible would be around 31 bytes (IV + padding).  What you claim is false.